# How can I return more than one file in the input file (HTML/JS) with this onActivityResult() (Java) function?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, android-afilechooser

Activity Result called by onShowFileChooser event:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
intent){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String s = "";
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        Uri[] results = null;
        //Check if response is positive
        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                if(null == mUMA){
                    return;
                }
                if(clipData == null){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "no clip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Uri uri = intent.getData();
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(uri.toString())};
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                    return;
                }else {
```

In the else statement I get the path of the files with for cycle and I put all paths in a string 's':

```
 for(int i=0; i<clipData.getItemCount(); i++){
         ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
         Uri uri = item.getUri();
         s+=uri.toString()+"\n";
 }
 results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(s)};
 mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
 return;
 }
```

But this function permits me to return just one file path of the intent and this one is the last file chosen:

```
mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
```

mUMA is a:

```
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
```